# codeigniter array session issue after move site one server(godaddy) to another server(bluehost)

Tags: session, codeigniter-3, php-5.2

There is issue  in  session.  This is my array.

print_r($this->session->userdata("user_data"));

```
       Array
         (
           [useremail] => myid@gmail.com
           [user_id] => 1
           [is_login] => 1
          )
```

I want to get the useremail . so I am writing this code.

```
         print_r($this->session->userdata("user_data")['useremail']);
```

It gives the error .  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

If I am writing the code like this :

$dataval = $this->session->userdata("user_data");

```
 print_r($dataval['useremail']);
```

Then it it working fine .

Please help me what is issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you (probably) moved from newer php version (5.4+) to older version (5.2).
Accessing array items directly by calling function name is only available on php 5.4 and newer: [array dereferencing](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62).

Only solution is to use temporary variable (like your `$dataval`). Or you can switch to newere php version, if the bluehost allows it.